# piexif Запись метаданных в фото

Tags: python

Пробую следующий код (записываю Key), использую популярную библиотеку piexif:

```
import piexif

exif_dict = piexif.load("test.jpg")

exif_dict["Exif"]['Key'] = '123123'
print(exif_dict)
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)

piexif.insert(exif_bytes, "test.jpg")
```

получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Python-tests/venv/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
  File "d:\Python-tests\venv\lib\site-packages\piexif\_dump.py", line 68, in dump
    exif_set = _dict_to_bytes(exif_ifd, "Exif", zeroth_length)
  File "d:\Python-tests\venv\lib\site-packages\piexif\_dump.py", line 325, in _dict_to_bytes
    key_str = struct.pack(">H", key)
struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: попробуйте '123123' без кавычек, что-ли...

Comment: неважно какой там текст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, it was an issue in the binary conversion. When I removed "AsShotNeutral" key from 0th worked:

```
import piexif

exif_dict = piexif.load("test.jpg")

del exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.AsShotNeutral] # <---- ADD THIS LINE

exif_dict["Exif"]['Key'] = '123123'
print(exif_dict)

exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)

piexif.insert(exif_bytes, "test.jpg")
```

If it doesn't work try removing the entire '0th' key:

```
del exif_dict["0th"]
```

A [similar issue](https://github.com/hMatoba/Piexif/issues/120) opened in the piexif github.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык